# menu tree with a simple filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I got a left menu tree which has too many nodes all till first level so I want to implement a search in tree nodes using java script. If some one types a query in search box all nodes at root and first level will be shown only if they contain the typed text query in expanded tree. Some thing like this :

[image]

Tree structure :

```
<input type="text" id="query" name="query">

    <ul id="sitemap">
          <li><a href="#">Places</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mercury</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Venus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Earth</a></li>
            </ul>                   
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Google</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>                   
        </li>
            .
            .
            .
    </ul>
```

For every onchange event do I have to create a new sub tree of original and display it or can I hide the nodes which do not contain the searched text in original tree. Any ideas?

Comment: You should work with the existing one, check every node's children and if they don't have the searched term hide that node. A simple recursive function can do this.

Comment: No need to create a new tree, you can simply hide the single `<li>` items. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am going to try same hiding li elements, just trying to figure out how to traverse through the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Got this working :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input#query').keyup(function(){

            var query = $('input#query').val().toLowerCase();

            if(query!="")
            {

                $("#sitemap li ul").show();


                var children = $("#sitemap li ul li a");
                for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                    //alert(children[i].parentNode.innerHTML);
                    if(children[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) == -1){
                        children[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
                    }else{
                        children[i].parentNode.style.display = "block";
                    }                               
                }
            }else{

                $("#sitemap li ul").hide();


                var children = $("#sitemap li ul li a");
                for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                            children[i].parentNode.style.display = "block";

                }

            }
        });
    });
```